# Show a paragraph, and hide another one with one click?

Tags: jquery

Well, I am trying to hide a `<p>` tag when you click on a link, and open an other `<p>` tag at the same moment.

But, I know it is easy but I can't get it to work...

So, can someone [**check my jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BCdMa/1/)? I did something wrong, and I can't get it to work.

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="$('.text1').hide('slow')" onclick="$('.text2').show('slow')">Read more</a>

<p class="text1">This is a randomtext.</p>
<p class="text2">This line will rule the world one day.</p>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.text2 {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to make use of [jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) and separate HTML from javascript. ([Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript))

Add a selector to your "read me" like this:

```
<a  class="readMore" >Read more</a>
```

And work with it in the `.js` file:

```
//using the .readMore class as a selector for the click event over it.
$('.readMore').click(function(){ 
    $('.text1').hide('slow');
    $('.text2').show('slow');
});
```

Here you have it working: http://jsfiddle.net/BCdMa/4/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need ?

```
<a onclick="$('.text1').hide('slow');$('.text2').show('slow')">Read more</a>
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/BCdMa/2/

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `toggle` method:

```
<a onclick="$('.text1, .text2').toggle('slow')">Read more</a>

<p class="text1">This is a randomtext.</p>
<p class="text2">This line will rule the world one day.</p>
```

and set the css like so:

```
a {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.text2{
    display:none;
}
```

[see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BCdMa/5/).